# AddThis toolbox multiple times

Tags: addthis

How can I do addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox') multiple times?
I have a list of posts, and each is opened in popup window (jquery ui dialog). So I need to reload AddThis bar for each post.

Now I have:

```
<div id="addThis_<?=$postID?>" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:title="<?=$fullTitle?>" addthis:url="https://<?=$url?>">
<a class="share-button addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="share-button addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="share-button addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="share-button addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="share-button addthis_button_twitter" addthis:title="<?=$fullTitle?>" addthis:url="http://lj.is/<?=$postID?>"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var addthis_config = {
data_track_clickback:true,data_track_addressbar:true,pubid:'...',ui_delay:300
};
var addthis_share = {url:"https://<?=$url?>", title:'<?=$fullTitle?>'};
if (window.addthis) {addthis.toolbox('#addThis_<?=$postID?>'); addthis.button("#addThis_<?=$postID?> .share-button"); addthis.counter("#addThis_<?=$postID?> .addthis_bubble_style");}
else $.getScript('https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=...&async=1', function(){addthis.init();});
})
</script>
```

Now first launch is ok. But next - bar is built, but without correct click, anchor title and etc.
You can see that on https://littlejoys.ru/

And additional problem - compact menu has incorrect position when my popup window is scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the div multiple times. But you need to change the URL, title, description using [Addthis optional attributes](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title) (addthis:url, addthis:title, addthis:description).

```
<!-- First Post -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="http://example.com/1"
        addthis:title="My cool first post"
        addthis:description="An Example Description 1">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=***"></script>

<!-- Second Post-->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="http://example.com/2"
        addthis:title="My hot second post"
        addthis:description="An Example Description 2">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=***"></script>
```

Therefore you can add it in a loop and it will pick up the correct data.

If Addthis is not getting re-initialized in UI dialog then you need to re-initialize the addthis buttons again using `addthis.button(".share-button")`

where share-button is the class of the addthis share anchor link.

Check this Addthis article: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365325-rendering-tools-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work too. I changed code in my question post to actual state.

Comment: And additional problem - compact menu has incorrect position when my popup window is scrolled.